# Is it possible to pass w3 xhtml strict validation and still use google analytic code on my webpage?

Tags: google-analytics, w3c-validation, xhtml-1.0-strict

Is it possible to pass w3 xhtml strict validation and still use google analytic code on my webpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If the specific code were to contain an &, >, or < (it doesn't), you would have to wrap the JavaScript in `<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[` and `//]]></script>` (ampersands are normally reserved for XML entities, and the others are for tags).

If you serve your web page using the XHTML MIME type `application/xhtml+xml` rather than the default HTML MIME type `text/html`, problems may result then. Serving pages under the latter MIME type only causes reduced cross-browser compatibilty and prevents many scripts from working. Though in the long term, I would focus on HTML5 compliance rather than XHTML compliance – that's the way further development of web standards is heading.

Comment: To be explicit, "reduced cross-browser compatibility" means that serving application/xhtml+xml means the page just flat out won't load IE 8 or lower (covering half the users on the internet).